# how to breakdown this line of code to create an add-on ? bpy

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

how to breakdown *(breakdown, apportionment)* this command line ?

**CODE LINE:**

```
bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 2, 0), "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "constraint_orientation":'GLOBAL', "mirror":False, "proportional":'DISABLED', "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":6.11591, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False}) to create an addon, from these instructions, I would like to have a couple of controls, text boxes that influence how many times to repeat operation.
```

1. number of times it doubles
2. axis where the duplicates are placed ( X ,Y ,Z )
3. relative offset ( X,Y,Z )
4. confirm action end

My problem is like breaking down that line of code in the necessary parts to convert it into an add-on.

I would like to have a couple of controls, text boxes that influence how many times to repeat operation.

[image: bpy how to drill down to create an add-on]
[image]

Comment: I do not understand *break down this line*. Do you want to replicate the ops command without an operator? If you know how to make an addon and got the command, what information are you looking for?

Answer (score 5):

You can find examples of creating add-ons and operators here:

[image]

As you can see to make any script an add-on you only need to add the information about it at the top:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "name of the add-on",
    "author": "Your Name Here",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 7, 9),
    "location": "some location",
    "description": "description of the add-on",
    "warning": "use warning",
    "wiki_url": "url of development or contact",
    "category": "corresponding category",
    }
```

Most likely you will want to create an operator for your add-on(**read the comments please**):

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "name of the add-on",
    "author": "Your Name Here",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 7, 9),
    "location": "Space Menu",
    "description": "Some description",
    "warning": "use warning",
    "wiki_url": "url of development or contact",
    "category": "Mesh",
    }

import bpy

class SomeOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operate"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.some_operator"
    bl_label = "Some Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    some_int = bpy.props.IntProperty(
            name="Some Int",
            default=2,
            description="some description",
            )
    some_value = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
            name="Some Value",
            default=2,
            description="some description",
            )
    # Properties you define here can be adjusted in the history panel after
    # the operator is used. you can find more about them at:
    # https://docs.blender.org/api/current/
    # you can use them in the operator with 'self.' so in this case you 
    # can access the property some_value as self.some_value

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None
    #The above bit describes circumstances that the operator is available in. 
    #In this case it is only available when some object in the scene is active.

    def execute(self, context): #This is what happens when you execute the operator
        # you can use other operators here that you see in the info panel
        # you can google each one you see for more info on how it is used
        for i in range(0, self.some_int):
            bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=False, mode='DUMMY')
            # I found info on bpy.ops.object.duplicate in the documentation:
            # https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78a/bpy.ops.object.html
            # that came up on Google when I searched for 'bpy.ops.object'

            bpy.context.object.location.y += self.some_value
        # note that I use Python function range() as well as for loop
        # you can learn more about Python at: www.python.org or www.w3schools.com

        return {'FINISHED'}


# Registration

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SomeOperator)
    # in order for it to work you need to register the operator

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SomeOperator)
    # and unregistered it for it to be properly deactivated without the need 
    # to restart Blender. 


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    register()
# This bit is only needed for it to work if you run it as a script as opposed
# to saving it to a file and installing it as an add-on
```

We only registered an operator and no UI for it so it is only possible to call it from the <kbd>Space</kbd> menu searching for it's bl_label, that in this case happens to be 'Some Operator'. You can adjust the properties after the operator is called in the history panel or in the <kbd>F6</kbd> panel. You can just run the script in Blender, however you can also save it to a file with .py extension and install it as an add-on.

[image]

Comment: @Nazgûl the code in answer does emulate duplicate move (to some extent) and adds a property to repeat.